# Small problem with (if) command in powershell

Tags: powershell

First, let me show you the code

```
$url = Read-Host 'URL'
if ( $url -gt '.'){
    msg * "The title does not contain(.)"
}
```

The code should alert you that the site does not have a dot

But either way the code alerts me

The code does not give me any error

Comment: What do you mean with "has no dot"? Like "hostname" vs. "hostname.domain"? The `-gt` operator seems a little far off for string comparison (what do you expect from `$url "greater than" '.'`?). Finally, the line `msg * "..."` also looks fishy syntax wise.

Comment: @Christian.K - The `msg * ...` line is legit; it's invoking the `msg.exe` utility, which simply pops up a dialog box with the message text and an OK button.

Comment: @Jeff Thanks! To add to my previous comment, I would have expected something along the lines of `if (!$url.Contains('.')) { msg * "Does not contain a dot" }`.

Comment: `! $url.Contains('.')` is propably the most efficient way. For completeness, using PowerShell operators: `$url -notlike '*.*'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-gt` operator does a case-insensitive lexical comparison, and where non-letters are involved, it uses case-folded Unicode ordering. The `.` is ordered before any of the letters, so virtually any URL, with or without a dot, will be lexically greater than the single dot you are comparing against.

If you want to test whether a string contains a dot, you should most likely be using [the `-match` or `-notmatch` operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.1); note that this uses [regular expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-7.1).

```
$url = Read-Host 'URL'
if ( $url -notmatch '\.'){
    msg * "The title does not contain(.)"
}
```

Comment: Thank you, you worked with me, but Can you make the message appear if (.) is not found twice

Comment: I would have to verify the regular expression, and I don't quite have time right now, but I _think_ you would want to match (or notmatch) against `\..*\.`